# I'm using Wincrypt for Diffie-Hellman-- can I export the shared secret in plain text?

Tags: cryptography, cryptoapi, diffie-hellman

OK-- thanks to [Mike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6970/mike-dimmick), I was able to get Wincrypt to generate a Diffie-Hellman keypair.  I figured out out to export the public key, and how to import the other party's public key.  According to the docs, upon import of the other party's public key, the shared secret has been computed.  Great.

I now need to get ahold of that shared secret, but I don't think its possible.  Simply calling `CryptExportKey` with a type of `PLAINTEXTKEYBLOB` fails unless I call `CryptSetKeyParam` to change the algorithm id from `CALG_AGREEDKEY_ANY` to something... else.  But I don't *want* something else, I want the shared secret.  The API, however, seems designed to discourage this.

Any ideas out there?  I should note that the problem here is that I'm only writing one side of an implementation of WiFi Protected Setup.  So the protocol is defined for me, and the other party is not giving me HCRYPTKEYs.

Comment: Was there ever a resolution to this? Running into a similar issue...

Answer (score 2):

**This looks like what you need...**
from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381969(VS.85).aspx

---

To import a Diffie-Hellman public key and calculate the secret session key

1. Call the `CryptAcquireContext` function to get a handle to the Microsoft Diffie-Hellman Cryptographic Provider.
2. Create a Diffie-Hellman key by calling the `CryptGenKey` function to create a new key, or by calling the `CryptGetUserKey` function to retrieve an existing key.
3. To import the Diffie-Hellman public key into the CSP, call the `CryptImportKey` function, passing a pointer to the public key BLOB in the `pbData` parameter, the length of the BLOB in the `dwDataLen` parameter, and the handle to the Diffie-Hellman key in the `hPubKey` parameter. This causes the calculation, `(Y^X) mod P`, to be performed, thus creating the shared, secret key and completing the key exchange. This function call returns a handle to the new, secret, session key in the `hKey` parameter.
4. At this point, the imported Diffie-Hellman is of type `CALG_AGREEDKEY_ANY`. Before the key can be used, it must be converted into a session key type. This is accomplished by calling the `CryptSetKeyParam` function with `dwParam` set to `KP_ALGID` and with `pbData` set to a pointer to a `ALG_ID` value that represents a session key, such as `CALG_RC4`. The key must be converted before using the shared key in the `CryptEncrypt` or `CryptDecrypt` function. Calls made to either of these functions prior to converting the key type will fail.
5. The secret session key is now ready to be used for encryption or decryption.
6. When the key is no longer needed, destroy the key handle by calling the `CryptDestroyKey` function.

Comment: +1 @Richard, Neat explanation. Your suggestion will solve key agreement scheme, but if i am interested in key transport using DH, how can i accomplish this task for a PKI?